# How do I get a DatePicker Fragment to notify Activity that fragment has been dismissed?

Tags: android, android-fragments, datepicker

When the user selects a date from a DatePicker dialog in a fragment the dialog and fragment are then dismissed. I want to be able to notify the originating activity so it can then run a toast.  I'd rather not add code to the fragment because it is already being used in many other places in the project.

Problem with current code is the toast runs as soon as the fragment dialog is created (the DatePicker).  Any ideas on how to fix?

Activity file:

```
...
DatePickerFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
Toast saveToast = Toast.makeText(this, "Now Click the Save Button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
saveToast.show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your fragment instance add code like this...

```
DatePickerFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
newFragment.setCallBack(ondate);
newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
```

and Initialize onDate as this

```
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener ondate = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker dp, int selectedYear,int selectedMonth, int selectedDay)
    {
         Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
         c.set(selectedYear, selectedMonth, selectedDay);
         String strDate = formatter.format(new Date(c.getTimeInMillis()));
         // here you can add toast or any thing
    }
};
```

Comment: See my above question where I mentioned: " I'd rather not add code to the fragment because it is already being used in many other places in the project."  Any ideas on how to do within the Activity rather than the fragment?

Comment: This code you needed to do in activity. In activity you are calling fragment to show. You just have to pass call back...in which you will get result. So in your activity you will get this result.

Comment: Ok, so the ondate code is the callback to the activity?

Comment: Yes, Fragment instance is in activity and then this call back will call when you select date from fragment.